# Switching content when tab selected using polymer ui elements tabs

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

I'm trying to use the `polymer-ui-tabs` component for a traditional tab component where you switch content based on which tab is selected. Unless I'm missing something the `polymer-ui-tabs` component only seems to provide the tab selector bit without an in built mechanism for switching content. Is that correct?

If it doesn't then how do I build that on top of it? The most likely thing I found was `onPolymerSelect` in `polymer_selector` but that method currently looks like this

```dart
Stream<CustomEvent> get onPolymerSelect {
  Element selection = $['selection'];
  if(selection != null) {
    // TODO return selection.onPolymerSelect;
  }
}
```

I just came across http://kevmoo.github.io/widget.dart/#tabswidget which I'll look into but just wanted to make sure I am not missing something before I pull in another library

Comment: I ported polymer-ui-tab to Dart but haven't yet used it myself. I found an example here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/QYe4TKR40EY. polymer-ui-animated-pages isn't ported yet, but polymer-ui-pages is. It's usage is probably similar.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer. I think I get it. Will try it out soon. Actually it looks really cool. Simple yet very flexible which is what I need as it will end up looking quite different to normal tabs and will likely be on the side, which should be easy to do with a grid layout

Answer (score 1):

Although it isn't in Dart, here's an example of how you can use `polymer-ui-tabs` and `polymer-ui-animated-pages` together to achieve the desired effect ([demo](http://jsbin.com/raqel/1/edit)):

index.html:

```dart
<!-- <script src="platform.js"></script>
     not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.14.0 -->
<script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>

<link rel="import" href="s-app.html">
<s-app></s-app>
```

s-app.html:

```dart
<link rel="import" href="polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="polymer-ui-tabs/polymer-ui-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="polymer-ui-animated-pages/polymer-ui-animated-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="polymer-flex-layout/polymer-flex-layout.html">

<polymer-element name="s-app">  
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
      polymer-ui-tabs {
        border-top: 1px solid #000;
      }
      polymer-ui-tabs > * {
        border-right: 1px solid #000;
      }
      header {
        padding: 10px;
        background: black;
        color: white;
      }
      polymer-ui-animated-pages > * {
        padding: 10px;
      }

    </style>
    <polymer-flex-layout vertical></polymer-flex-layout>
    <header>
      Header
    </header>
    <polymer-ui-animated-pages selected="{{page}}" flex>
      <div>Page One</div>
      <div>Page Two</div>
      <div>Page Three</div>
    </polymer-ui-animated-pages>
    <polymer-ui-tabs selected="{{page}}">
      <span flex>One</span>
      <span flex>Two</span>
      <span flex>Three</span>
    </polymer-ui-tabs>
  </template>

  <script>
    // switch page on tab
    Polymer('s-app', {page:0});
  </script>

</polymer-element>
```

As you can see, binding the current selection between the tab element and the animated page allows you to switch to the desired content for a tab.

Comment: Thank you for the example but unfortunately polymer-ui-animated-pages is not yet ported to Dart.