# Google Dart Pages within Tabs

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements, core-elements

I'm attempting to load "pages" within tabs in Dart and can not seem to set them up properly.  My below example has pages that are supposed to show text inputs on each page but the pages are within tabs. I'm not sure how to properly set these pages up within tabs.  So far I had been going by this example: [Switching content when tab selected using polymer ui elements tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815936/switching-content-when-tab-selected-using-polymer-ui-elements-tabs)  Please let me know if you need more information.

```dart
<paper-tabs id="Tabs" selected="0" style='width:800px; height:175px; color:green;'>

 <paper-tab id="systemtab"> System
 <core-pages selected="0">
  <paper-input id='version' label="Version:" readonly></paper-input>
</core-pages>
 </paper-tab>
 <paper-tab id="userTab"> User
  <core-pages selected="1">
  <paper-input id='Welcome' label="Display Welcome Page:" readonly></paper-input>
  <paper-input id='user_name' label="User Name:" readonly></paper-input>
  </core-pages>
 </paper-tab>

 </paper-tabs>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and it worked so far:

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel='import' href='../../packages/paper_elements/paper_tabs.html'>
<link rel='import' href='../../packages/paper_elements/paper_tab.html'>
<link rel='import' href='../../packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html'>
<link rel='import' href='../../packages/core_elements/core_pages.html'>

<polymer-element name="app-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-tabs id="Tabs" selected="{{page}}" style='width:800px; height:175px; color:green;'>
      <paper-tab>System</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>User</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>

    <core-pages selected="{{page}}">
      <div>
        <paper-input id='version' label="Version:" readonly></paper-input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <paper-input id='Welcome' label="Display Welcome Page:" readonly></paper-input>
        <paper-input id='user_name' label="User Name:" readonly></paper-input>
      </div>
    </core-pages>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="app_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('app-element')

class AppElement extends PolymerElement {

  @observable
  int page = 0;

  AppElement.created() : super.created();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel='import' href='../../packages/paper_elements/paper_tabs.html'>
<link rel='import' href='../../packages/paper_elements/paper_tab.html'>
<link rel='import' href='../../packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html'>
<link rel='import' href='../../packages/core_elements/core_pages.html'>

<polymer-element name="app-element">
  <template>
    <paper-tabs id="tabs">
      <paper-tab>System</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>User</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>

    <core-pages selected="{{$.tabs.selected}}">
      <div>
        <paper-input id='version' label="Version:" readonly></paper-input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <paper-input id='Welcome' label="Display Welcome Page:" readonly></paper-input>
      </div>
    </core-pages>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="app_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

It would be nice to be able to bind without have to create a "pages" attribute.  I have seen examples use the expression "{{$.id.attribute}}"

Comment: Your expression only works in Polymer.js but in Dart because in Dart you would need to write `{{$['id'].attribute}}` and as far as I know `[]` are still not supported in Dart Polymer expressions.

Comment: @sabrooks Did you get the above answer to work? I tried it and I cannot get the pages to display apart from the initially selected page. I see the tabs and the yellow bar moves but there is no display of the contents of the pages corresponding to the tabs. Thanks.