# Dart Core Pages Selector Detection

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements, core-elements

I'm attempting to accomplish page change detection through core-pages in a Polymer element http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-pages, so I can load appropriate methods for each.  Right now, the Dart snippet is initialized within the init method (the first one that launches when the application starts).  I'm not sure how to keep track of when the pages change and also a decent way to detect updates (so I can at least see the different LOG updates in the snippet below).  The code heavily relates to this question: [Google Dart Pages within Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100401/google-dart-pages-within-tabs).  Please let me know if you need more information.

HTML:

```dart
 <paper-tabs id="Tabs" selected="{{page}}" style='width:800px; height:50px; color:#333333;'>
      <paper-tab>Display 1</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>Display 2</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>

    <core-pages selected="{{page}}">
   </core-pages>
```

Dart:

```dart
@observable int page = 0;

var pages = shroot.querySelector("core-pages");
     pages.onChange.listen((e) {
            //keep for debugging
                 if (pages == 0) {
                   _LOG.info("properties 1 selected");
                   display();
                 } else if (pages == 1) {
                   _LOG.info("properties 2 selected");
                   display();
                 }
          });
```

Comment: I can't seem to see any LOG outputs.  Is it actually setup right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any `change` event in `core-pages` or its super classes.

I think this is the simplest way doing it:

```dart
  @observable int page = 0;

  void pageChanged(oldValue, newValue) {
  //keep for debugging
    if (page == 0) {
      _LOG.info("properties 1 selected");
      display();
    } else if (page == 1) {
      _LOG.info("properties 2 selected");
      display();
    }
  }
```

If you prefer listening to events, `core-pages` extends `core-selector` which has
- `core-select` - sent twice for deselect (old) and select (new). You need access to the event details to know which one it is and that is currently difficult because you need dart-js-interop
- `core-activate` - fired when an item element is tapped. Not sure if it fires when the selection changes by binding and you also need access to the event.details to get which page is actually selected.

Comment: If you have an `@observable int page = 0` in the same class `pageChanged` is called whenever the value of `page` changes. This is a feature of `Observable` (which you get automatically when you extend `PolymerElement`

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use to get the selection change event on core-pages:

```dart
<core-pages on-core-select='{{pageChange}}' id='pager' selected="{{page}}">
  <!-- content page widgets -->
</core-pages>
```

then in Dart

```dart
void pageChange(Event e, d, _){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  if(d['item'] is! ContentPage) return;

  if (d['isSelected']){
    d['item'].loaded();
  }else{
    d['item'].unloaded();
  }
}
```

All of my content pages implement a mixin `ContentPage` that has `.loaded()` & `.unloaded()` methods, so that's how I alert each content page that it is now selected or unselected.  I did this because core-pages loads all the content into the DOM at runtime.